# Adding `true` as a parameter to a method that should have no parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm looking through some code and I discovered this one liner:

```
@order = current_order(true)
```

Here's the method the programmer wrote:

```
def current_order
  @user.orders.incomplete.last
end
```

I don't see a parameter for `current_order` anywhere. Can someone explain why this works or why he did it?

Comment: No error you found, I mean `Argumenterror` ? I suspect, there 2 methods with same name but different signature exist.

Comment: Nope. That's what's confusing me! Its not breaking...

Comment: You should be missing something. You need to show more relavant code around it.

Comment: Have you looked at `method(:current_order)` where `current_order(true)` is called to make sure it is the same `current_order` method you think it is?

Comment: Adding true as a parameter for something that does not need any parameters usually should not matter. DId you try to remove the true? DOes this crash the code?

Comment: Adding true as a parameter does matter, it will throw `ArgumentError`

Comment: I've searched throughout our Github repo. It breaks when I test it in IRB at version 2.1.1 and again at 1.9.3.

Comment: Found it. Located here inside [spree](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/95e5f930c03f53cc01b3950d9b9d9a683e72f429/core/lib/spree/core/controller_helpers/order.rb#L20).

Comment: @BenMorganIO you can [answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just a hunch, but I suspect the method definition for current_order that you listed is probably in a test helper whereas the method call that uses current_order(true) is in non-test code and so it uses  the current_order method that is defined in spree_frontend, specifically  in the Spree::Core::ControllerHelpers::Order module

Comment: Thanks Francois. `bundle open spree` within an old branch: `@order = current_order`. `bundle open spree` within `spree-security-update` branch after `bundle update spree`: `@order = current_order(lock: true)`.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know what the lock parameter does?

Comment: the current_order method, as defined in Spree::Core::ControllerHelpers::Order (see https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/lib/spree/core/controller_helpers/order.rb#L20) accepts the lock parameter and uses it for row-level locking in the database.

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html for more information on pessimistic locking in Rails.

Answer (score 0):

One explanation is that you have current_order declared somewhere else. To prove that you can try to use:

```
current_order
```

According to my theory that should break, since the argument version won (ruby does not support multiple signatures methods).

Comment: But you still can't know if it's an optional argument, which should be the case not to break existing code when overriding a method

Comment: True - so if current_order does not break, he should delete "true" version and it will still work.

Answer (score 0):

I know you found it inside one of your gems, but for future reference, here's some bash script to search your codebase for the method definition(s).

```
find app lib vendor $GEM_HOME -print | awk '{print "\""$0"\""}' | xargs grep -n "def current_order"
```

The `$GEM_HOME` part assumes you are using RVM, which uses a $GEM_HOME environment variable.  If you're not, replace `$GEM_HOME` with the location of your gems folder.

This would have shown you the two locations where the method is defined.